# How to conditionally set a value to parent field based on another field inside an array in mongodb aggregate?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I want to set a variable at a function level from inside the aggregate map operator. Here is a snippet of what I have till now.

```
$project: {
  collectionId: 1,
  name: 1,
  description: 1,
  image: 1,
  created: 1,
  updated: 1,
  isPresent: "no",
  "products": {
    $map: {
      "input": "$products",
      as: "product",
      in: {
        "title": "$$product.name",
        "imageUrl": "$$product.mainImage",
        "productId": "$$product.productId",
        "$isPresent": "yes"
      }
    }
  },
  total: {
    $size: "$products"
  },
  userId: "$user.userId",
  userName: "$user.name",
}
```

I want to set the isPresent node value to yes inside the map operator at in based on a condition. For the time being I have kept it to just yes. But this doesn't work.

What is the way to do it?

Comment: what is the condition that you wanted to check on `products` array ? Maybe better explain more on what cases of product makes parent field `isPresent : 'Yes'`

Comment: I have a local variable called productId ... I am checking if that productId is equal to any of the productIds inside the products array.

Comment: there is both `isPresent` and `$isPresent`, which one do you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/in/index.html#in-aggregation) and [$cond](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/index.html) operators :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    /** `$products.productId` gives an array of 'productId''s from products array */
    {
      $addFields: { isPresent: { $cond: [ { $in: [ 2, "$products.productId" ] }, "Yes", "No" ] } }
    }
  ])
```

**Test :** [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/x4ulIhhQ_0u)

**Note :**

As we're using `$in` each document going through this has to have `products` array, otherwise `$in` will error out, if there are any such cases you need to have to condition to skip for those docs which don't have `products` array.